# How To Convert Weakly Typed JSON Into C# Readable Object

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF service that reads JSON from a Non .NET HTTP Request.  I would like to use JSON.NET or some other tool to convert that JSON into a weakly typed object that can be read on the server side in C#.  I hope not to have to create WCF data contacts for this process. I do not know the full schema of the returned JSON. Also, it may vary. I'm looking for something generic. Any suggestions on available tools for this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it may vary but you have a few fixed types right?   do you have types that will work for most situations?

Otherwise, maybe you can use DeserializeAnonymousType()